How to add Custom Button in Angular TinyMCE
My requirement is to add the custom button/menu to add the form elements with in TinyMCE Angular editor.
Here is the template code i have used. My requirement is to add the new button in the toolbar or anywhere within editor.
`<editor
    apiKey="2zr2n................................g26r3pdhfruj"
    formControlName="body"
    [init]="{ 
      plugins: 'advlist autolink link image lists',
      toolbar: 'paste undo redo',
    }"
></editor>`

This is the code i have tried to use in ts file.
`OnInit(editor) {
    editor.ui.registry.addButton('test', {
      text: 'My button',
      icon: false,
      onclick: function () {
        alert('test')
      }
    })   
  }`


You are using wrong properties.

icon is defined as string and not as boolean. The string indicates which icon is used
onclick does not exist on ToolbarButtonSpec. Use onAction instead

interface ToolbarButtonSpec extends BaseToolbarButtonSpec<ToolbarButtonInstanceApi> {
    type?: 'button';
    onAction: (api: ToolbarButtonInstanceApi) => void;
}

interface BaseToolbarButtonSpec<I extends BaseToolbarButtonInstanceApi> {
    enabled?: boolean;
    tooltip?: string;
    icon?: string;
    text?: string;
    onSetup?: (api: I) => (api: I) => void;
}

